# Pass a parameter from one controller to another controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller-extension, parameters

I would like to know how to pass a parameter from one controller to another controller?

For example I am trying to pass the accountId value by using the following code in the first controller

```
public PageReference goToNextPage() {
    PageReference pageRef = Page.MyNextPage;
    pageRef.getParameters().put('AccId', accountId);
    return pageRef;
}
```

Page

```
<apex:page standardController="Lead" extensions="LeadToMerchConvertController">
  <apex:form > 
     <apex:pageBlock > 
        <apex:pageMessages > </apex:pageMessages> 
     </apex:pageBlock> 
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public with sharing class LeadToMerchConvertController { 

       Lead objLead; 
       public static String accountId; 
       public LeadToMerchConvertController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
       { 
         objLead = (Lead)controller.getRecord();
         System.debug(ApexPages.currentPage()); 
         accountId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('AccId');
         System.debug('accountId ' + accountId); 
         ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.WARNING,'There is an existing Merchant: ' + accountId + ''); 
         ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg); 
      } 
}
```

and according to the log file

```
DEBUG|pageRef System.PageReference[/apex/newconvtomerch?AccId=00156000002zGVsAAM
```

the value I need is added to the AccId.

The problem is that by using the following code

```
String AccountId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('AccId');
```

I can not get the AccId value in the second controller which actually is the Extension controller

Could you please advise how to fetch the AccId value I need from the first controller?

Regards,

​Dilyan

Comment: Hi Dylan. Can you please let me know the second page url like this.  `/apex/newconvtomerch?AccId=00156000002zGVsAAM` ?

Comment: Here is the second page url 
System.debug(ApexPages.currentPage());
DEBUG|System.PageReference[/apex/newConvToMerch

Comment: looks like you are passing AccountId. Can you please add your both page and controller in question section?

Comment: Hi here is the page code

<apex:page standardController="Lead" extensions="LeadToMerchConvertController">
  <apex:form >
   <apex:pageBlock >
      <apex:pageMessages >
      </apex:pageMessages>   
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>  
</apex:page>

Comment: public with sharing class LeadToMerchConvertController {
    Lead objLead;
    public static String accountId; 
    public LeadToMerchConvertController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        objLead = (Lead)controller.getRecord();
        System.debug(ApexPages.currentPage());
  accountId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('AccId');
  System.debug('accountId ' + accountId);        
        ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.WARNING,'There is an existing Merchant: ' + accountId + '');
        ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);   
    }

Comment: and the corresponding controller

Comment: `goToNextPage` this method in which controller ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32352/discussion-between-ratan-and-dylan-d).

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
public PageReference goToNextPage() {

    return new PageReference('/apex/newconvtomerch?AccId='+accountId);
}
```

Comment: Hi here is the page code

<apex:page standardController="Lead" extensions="LeadToMerchConvertController">
  <apex:form >
   <apex:pageBlock >
      <apex:pageMessages >
      </apex:pageMessages>   
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>  
</apex:page>

Comment: Hi, I've tried what you suggested but still the value of the AccId is not passed to the extension controller

Answer (score 0):

I believe you simply need to set the redirect attribute of the `pageReference` to true before returning it.

```
public PageReference goToNextPage() {
    PageReference pageRef = Page.MyNextPage;
    pageRef.getParameters().put('AccId', accountId);
    pageRef.setRedirect(true);
    return pageRef;
}
```

The redirect attribute is false by default, which [according to the setRedirect documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_System_PageReference_setRedirect.htm) will perform a server-side redirect.

By contrast, setting redirect to true will cause your browser to fire a new GET request. The `pageReference` parameters are passed as a query string in the URL, so the GET request is required to pass that information to your next controller.